# UI Test Case XCUIElementTypeQueryProvider tableRows and tableColumns count is 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing, xcuielementtypequeryprovider

I am trying to test whether the `UITableView` has at least first cell available or not.

```
func testFirstCellIsAvailable() throws {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    let tablesQuery = app.tables
    XCTAssertNotNil(tablesQuery.cells.staticTexts["John"], "First Cell should be John")
            
}
```

This is one of the simplest way to find the TableView is loaded or not.

However , I see `XCUIElementQuery` has `tableRows` and `tableColumns`, when I check the value it's always zero. So the question is when do we use `tableRows` and `tableColumns`

For the above example value of `app.tableRows.count` and `app.tableColumns.count` is 0.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableColumns` and `tableRows` are usually seen in 2D tables, while "flat" UITableView consist of `cells`. For example, you can see such elements if you create a table in macOS Notes application and inspect `XCUIApplication`

Comment: Oh that's interesting this property is used by macOS component. but it would be nice if It was documented with Apple Docs.